# Test file for specific permissions

Tags: bash, scripting, file-permissions

I have a script where I'd like to test a file for specific permissions, specifically 0644, if it is not that then chmod it.

I know I could just chmod it and let it fall through in case it already was that way but I'd like to print a message of it's previous value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MYFILE=./myfile
```

For readability I'm using `u=rw,go=r` instead of octal `0644`.
I'm assuming that you wish to set the missing permissions , but if there are extra permissions present, you want to let them be as they are.
Step by step:

```
PREV_PERM="`find \"\$MYFILE\" \! -perm -u=rw,go=r -ls`"
echo "$PREV_PERM"
chmod u+rw,go+r "$MYFILE"
```

or combine it into neat one-liner instead:

```
find "$MYFILE" '!' -perm -u=rw,go=r -ls -exec chmod u+rw,go+r "$MYFILE" ';'
```